# Base-class pointer pointing to a derived class cannot access derived-class method

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-functions, dynamic-binding, method-hiding

I am learning inheritance in C++11, and I found that if a derived class has redefined a virtual function name but with a different prototype, a base-class pointer assigned with a pointer to the derived class can only access the base class version of the function. The derived version function cannot be accessed. I wonder why this happens.

```
class Enemy {
public:
  virtual void describe() { std::cout << "Enemy"; }
};
class Dragon : public Enemy {
public:
  virtual void describe(int dummy) { std::cout << "Dragon"; }
};
```

In `main`,

```
Dragon foo;
Enemy* pe = &foo;
pe->describe(); // Enemy
foo.describe(1); // Dragon
pe->describe(1); // no matching function, candidate is Enemy::describe()
```

From what I know about virtual function tables, the derived object that `pe` points to (i.e. `foo`) should have a vpointer member that points to `Dragon`'s vtable. I also know that redefinition of a function name in the derived class will hide all the functions of the same name in the base class. So in Dragon's vtable the address of 'describe' should be the function with parameter `int dummy`.

But it turns out that `pe` can access `Enemy`'s version of the method, which is supposed to be hided. And `pe` cannot access `Dragon`'s version of the method, which is supposed to be in `pe`'s vtable. It performs as if the `Enemy`'s vtable is used. Why this happens?

**Update**:
I think now I more or less understand the mechanisms behind it. Here is my hypothesis:

Since it is a pointer to `Enemy`, the program will first find the method name in `Enemy`'s scope. If the name is not found, the compiler gives an error. If it is not virtual, then call it. If it is virtual, then record the method's offset in `Enemy`'s vtable. Then the program use this offset to access the right method in the target object's vtable.

If the method is properly overrided, the function address in target object's vtable at that offset would have been changed. Otherwise, it will be the same function address as in the `Enemy`'s vtable, as in the example.

Since `Dragon`'s `describe` with `int dummy` is a different prototype, it is added to the `Dragon`'s vtable after the original `describe` it inherited from Enemy. But the `int dummy` version cannot be accessed from `Enemy*` because `Enemy`'s vtable doesn't even have that offset.

Is this correct?

Comment: `pe` is using the `Enemy` API, and the method being accessed is not part of that API.

Comment: I have updated my hypothesis on what's happening in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you have:

```
class Enemy {
public:
  virtual void describe() { std::cout << "Enemy"; }
};

class Dragon : public Enemy {
public:
  // void describe() override { Enemy::describe(); } // Hidden
  virtual void describe(int dummy) { std::cout << "Dragon"; }
};
```

Selection of overload method is done statically:

- pointers/references on `Enemy` only see `void Enemy::describe()`
- pointers/references on `Dragon` only see `void Dragon::describe(int)` (but could explicitly have access to `void Enemy::describe()`).

Then virtual dispatch is done with runtime type.

So

```
Dragon foo;
Enemy* pe = &foo;

foo.describe();         // KO: Enemy::describe() not visible (1)
foo.Enemy::describe();  // OK: Enemy::describe()
foo.describe(1);        // OK: Dragon::describe(int)

pe->describe();         // OK: Enemy::describe()
pe->describe(1);        // KO: No Enemy::describe(int)
pe->Dragon::describe(1);// KO: Dragon is not a base class of Enemy
```

(1) can be fixed by changing `Dragon` with

```
class Dragon : public Enemy {
public:
  using Enemy::describe; // Unhide Enemy::describe()

  virtual void describe(int dummy) { std::cout << "Dragon"; }
};
```

Comment: But why `pe->describe` is static binding (dispatch) instead of dynamic binding? I assumed that during runtime, when the program is trying to dispatch a virtual method, it will look into the virtual function table of the object. In this case it is `Dragon`'s vtable.

Comment: `void (C::*)describe()` and `void (C::*)describe(int)` are 2 different signatures. Dragon vtable would have 2 entries, one for `Enemy::describe()` (which it doesn't override, so would have same value than an `Enemy` instance), one for `Dragon::describe(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions with the same name but different signatures are essentially different functions.

By declaring `virtual void describe(int dummy)` in your `Dragon` class, you have declared a new virtual function, not overriding the original one (`virtual void describe()` in `Enemy`). You can only override virtual functions with the same signature.

You cannot call `describe(1)` on a pointer to `Enemy` because c++ calls function according to the instance's compile time type (although such a call can be dynamically dispatched to call the actual overrode method).

Comment: But why here the function is dispatched at compile time but not runtime? From my understanding, if the function is dispatched during runtime, the program should be able to find a `describe` in `Dragon`'s vtable, though it is unrelated to the `describe` in `Enemy`. Is this true?

Comment: @Elucidase The function is there in the vtable, but cannot be accessed from a pointer to `Enemy`, because `Enemy` does not have that member function (it has one with the same name, but not the same member function).

Comment: @Elucidase Also, think from the perspective of the compiler. If you have another type, say, `Soldier` that also derives from `Enemy`, that has the `describe` method, but with signature `describe()` (without `int`). You give the compiler a pointer to `Enemy`, and call `describe(1)` on it. How would the compiler know at the compiler whether it has `Dragon` type or `Soldier` type? Virtual methods is a good way to create a **solid** interface for function calling, not to improvise on various parameters.

Comment: But when the function is properly overrided, the program can access `Dragon`'s vtable from a `Enemy*` pointer. And from what I learned, it seems vtable and dynamic dispatch are exactly the mechanisms to deal with the situations where the type is not known during compile time.

Comment: @Elucidase What you are suggesting is theoretically possible (evidence: there is `dynamic_cast` in c++), but they are simply not permitted in your context.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, functions that have the same name but different parameters are completely independent functions, ***that have nothing to do with each other***. The fact that they have the same name is completely immaterial.

It is exactly the same as if you called the function in the base class "apple", and the one in the derived class "banana". Since there is no "banana" function in the base class, you cannot obviously call it in the base class. The banana function in the derived class obviously does not override the function in the base class.

> I also know that redefinition of a function name in the derived class
>   will hide all the functions of the same name in the base class.

That is incorrect. It hides it only if it has the same name, but also identical parameters (and any qualifiers, if there are or are not any).